# text file multiply bash linux

Tags: bash, file, text, lines, repeat

for example i have a text file with 5 lines:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

and i want to make a script to make a 2000 lines file containing loops of the file above
and it would look like

```
    one
    two
    three
    four
    five
    one
    two
    three
    four
    five
    one
    two
    three
    four
    five
 ............repeat until n times is reached
```

Answer (score 6):

Testing showed this to be about 100 times faster than the next best approach given so far.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

IN="${1}"
OUT="${2}"

for i in {1..2000}; do
    echo "${IN}"
done | xargs cat > "${OUT}"
```

The reason this is so much faster is because it doesn't repeatedly open, seek to end, append, and close the output file. It opens the output file once, and streams the data to it in a single large, continuous write. It also invokes `cat` as few times as possible. It may invoke `cat` only once, even, depending on the system's maximum command line length and the length of the input file name.

Comment: Why not `echo "$LIST" > "$OUT"`? What are `xargs` and `cat` for?

Comment: @Dennis: `echo "$LIST" > "$OUT"` would give you an output file containing 2000 instances of the input file name.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. The problem with that approach is that you could exceed the argument length limit.

Comment: @Dennis: That's what `xargs` is for ;)

Comment: You don't need the `$LIST` variable: `for i in {1..2000}; do echo "$IN"; done | xargs cat > "$OUT"`

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, that's even better. I didn't know about redirecting and/or piping after loops until now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

If you need to repeat 2000 times

```
for i in {1..2000}; do cat "FILE"; done > NEW_FILE
```

Comment: Move the redirection to the end and it might be a little faster (and use `>` instead of `>>` and you won't need to worry whether the file needs to be emptied first).

Comment: @Dennis: How can the redirection be moved to the end? The only way I can think of is to put the loop in a function. E.g. call the function `repeat` and do `repeat "${INPUT}" > "${OUTPUT}"`. This is still a slow method because `cat` gets invoked 2000 times.

Comment: @Dan: The revised answer shows that. The original version of this answer was: `for i in {1..2000}; do cat FILE >> NEW_FILE; done`. The reason the revised version might be slightly faster is that the output file doesn't have to be repeatedly opened.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks! I didn't know you could redirect after a loop like that. Neat! Still, it's better if you minimize the invocations of `cat` ;) Mine finishes in 6 hundreths of a second. This one still takes several seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need 2000 lines or 2000 copies of the original file?

If the first:

```
infile='/path/to/inputfile'
outfile='/path/to/outputfile'
len=$(wc -l < "$infile")
for ((i=1; i<=2000/len; i++))
do
    cat "$infile"
done > "$outfile.tmp"    # you can use mktemp or tempfile if you want
head -n 2000 "$outfile.tmp" > "$outfile"
rm "$outfile.tmp"
```

If the second:

```
for i in {1..2000}; do cat "$infile"; done > "$outfile"
```

For a small input file (avoids the overhead of forking `cat` 2000 times):

```
file=$(<"$infile"); for i in {1..2000}; do echo "$file"; done > "$outfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a script? If you just want to quickly generate that you can open on vim, cut (press esc than 5dd to cut 5 lines) and than insert n times (press esc than n p to paste n times).

**Edit:** if you absolutely need a script and efficiency is not a problem, you can do this "dirty" trick:

```
i=0;
n=5;
while(($i < $n)) ; do
    cat orginal_file >> new_file;
    let i+=1;
done
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop and let Bash manage the variable. `for ((i=0; i<n; i++))`.

Comment: `for i in {1..100};`

Answer (score 0):

```
file_size() {
    cat -- "$@" |wc -l
}

mult_file() {
    local \
        max_lines="$1" \
        iter_size \
        iters \
        i

    shift 1

    iter_size="$(file_size "$@")"

    let iters=max_lines/iter_size+1

    (for ((i=0; i<iters; ++i)); do
        cat -- "$@"
    done) |
    head --lines="$max_lines"
}

mult_file "$@"
```

So you would call it like `script.sh LINES FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 >REPEAT_FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

No process in the loop, no pipes:

```
infile='5.txt'
outfile='2000.txt'

n=$((2000/ $(wc -l < "$infile") ))      # repetitions

> "$outfile"                            # empty output file

IFS=''
content=$(cat "$infile")                # file content as string

for (( CNTR=0; CNTR<n; CNTR+=1 )); do
  echo "$content" >> "$outfile"
done
```